# Как перемещать объект в определенную сторону не смотря на то куда он повернут?

Tags: c#, unity3d, vector

Есть объект, он перемещается в определенную сторону вот так:  transform.Translate(0,0,speed*Time.deltaTime);
Есть второй объект, он должен перемещаться в том же направлении что и первый,
cub.transform.Translate(0,0,speed*Time.deltaTime); -если у него будет такой код, то когда он повернется в другую сторону он будет направляться в свое прямо, а не в сторону куда направляется второй объект.
Ответ типо получать координаты первого объекта и присваивать второму не верен, нужно именно направление.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно указать что двигаешь в мировых координатах.
Должно помочь.

```
transform.Translate(someVector, Space.World);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло